# How can I build a CountIF function in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, function

CountIF function in excel , How do I use the same function in
sharepoint Calculated Field. 
I want count number of "GO" from Column 1 to Column 12
i.e. Col 1 "GO", Col 2 "GO", Col 3 "No GO", Col 4 "GO": GOs=3

Answer (score 4):

There is no CountIF in SharePoint

- [Windows SharePoint Services - Formulas and Functions Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/CH100650061033.aspx)

So instead you're going to have to use a Calculated Column set to Number and a formula like

```
=IF([Column1]="GO",1,0) + IF([Column2]="GO",1,0) + ...
```

For 12 columns you're going to run in to a [limit of how many nested If's you can have - this post will give you some options.](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/04/12/maximum-number-of-if-statements-in-a-calculated-column/)

The alternative is to calculate the "Number of Gos" column in code using either Workflow or an Event Receiver or even a funky javascript hack on the NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx